# Redirect domain.org to www.domain.org

Tags: wordpress, redirect, apache2

I have the following doubt.

On a Debian server with apache I have a wordpress published with the domain "mydomain.org".

I want to be able to do the following:

When in the browser I write `http://mydomain.tld` it redirects me to `http://www.mydomain.tld`, that is, redirect a non-www request to www request.

When accessing `http://mydomain.tld`, what appears on the screen is the "Locked Page" message from the firewall in front of us, so I understand that the problem itself is on the side of the firewall in the configuration itself of the WAF.

Can it be correct?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Imrpoved formatting

Answer (score 0):

1) Create an .htaccess file in your root directory where wordpress exist. If you already have an .htaccess file in the root directory, you can modify it.

2) Copy and paste the following lines of text into the .htaccess file: **paste any one code as per your requirements.**

```
#Remove www from any URLs that have them: Paste any one code
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]



#Add www to any URLs that do not have them: paste any one code
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

3) Replace example.com in the final line of text with your own domain name.

4) Save the .htaccess file.

5) To test the configuration, use your web browser to visit http://www.example.com, where example.com represents your domain name. The browser should be redirected to http://example.com.